# When a low-rep user suggests many edits to old posts?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

Today I have seen that some low-rep. user has been suggesting edits to many posts. Generally, this is a good thing. However many of these posts were *old* (at least a month old), and often downvoted. The changes themselves were not always significant.

Since the review page does not tell you whether another user has reviewed and approved/rejected this, and most people would usually approve a reasonable grammatical/LaTeX edit (even without checking timestamps), many of the edits went through.

When something like that happens, and I feel reluctant to approve the edits, but I also feel that the user is acting badly, what sort of action should I take?

Comment: You should open a thread on meta, asking for advice. Oh, wait....

Comment: @Gerry: I once played the game of wait with a wall and won. I can wait... :-)

Comment: I think I know the user you are writing about. I've left a comment on one recent edit, asking said user to slow down, keep it to maybe three edits a day. But I think direct communication from a moderator may be in order.

Comment: @Gerry: I strongly agree with that. As a matter of fact the first thing I did after posting this thread was to flag it with the user details, to communicate to the moderators the case which brought this issue up.

Comment: If they continue, they will soon reach 1000 rep and need to find another avenue to get reputation.

Comment: @robjohn: I thought that you need a 3,000 rep threshold for that.

Comment: One can only gain [1000 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) from suggested edits.

Comment: @robjohn: Oh. Well, either way this is still something to be addressed when done on such a short timespan. :-)

Comment: As with [the last time this happened](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4966/unnecesarily-retagging-old-questions-that-get-bumped), empirically the most effective response is to leave a comment politely asking the user to take it easy. @Gerry, perhaps you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Rahul, I made *two* comments in this thread --- but I think I know which one you mean.

Comment: @Will: I disagree. The age of the post is a factor when weighing in the amount of changes. Just changing one letter is not a good enough reason to bump a two years old post.

Comment: @Gerry: ...and that is why I sometimes hate talking with mathematicians! :-)

Comment: @Asaf: While you say the age of the post should be a factor, it seems the community disagreed [when you asked about it on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2401/856). For what it's worth, I agree with your position, but it doesn't seem to be the consensus.

Comment: @Rahul: I completely forgot about that... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was tempted to write an answer to this, just because of how much I disagree with the importance you give to the age of a post. And saying that a post is old if it is older than a month makes this position even more extreme. I occasionally decide to do the required reading of some background material to be "entitled" to write an answer to an interesting [question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/problem-of-induction-without-i-i-d/3137#3137) (so admittedly this situation is more typical for philosophy than for math), and such reading can easily exceed a month.

Comment: @Thomas: I never said "don't edit old posts". I did say "*if you only edit two lowercase `i` to an uppercases `I` and the post is two years old, please don't.*" but feel free to write an answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The comments by WillHunting and RahulNarain already made it clear that I don't need to defend my opinion about old posts by writing an answer. I still wrote a comment, because the sheer volume of questions on MSE makes the otherwise nice experience less enjoyable for me, and I didn't like to hear your confirmation that a post is already old after a month. Perhaps I should really ask a question on meta about this, but I'm not sure whether I'm the sufficiently typical user of MSE to criticize the direction it is currently heading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At Rahul's suggestion, comment becomes answer:

I left a comment on one recent edit, asking the user to slow down, maybe keep it to three edits a day. The user has responded favorably so, one hopes, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should forget about the age of the posts, and focus on the content of the edits. If the edits themselves were good, then you should approve them, otherwise you should not. If someone has the time to run through old posts to edit them, all the more power to them. Then they deserve those 2 measly rep points, because they improve the site, do they not? I've made a couple of recent edits on old posts myself, but I don't look for them. Instead, I found those posts googling for an answer to a question I had, and after noticing LaTeX rendering errors I figured why not make it clearer. I probably wasn't the last person to stumble upon that post, so it might be helpful to others, as well.

To sum it up, judge the edits on their own merits, and forget about everything else related to the post. This site is an archive of answered and unanswered questions, and in that sense an encyclopedia of knowledge. All improvements should therefore be more than welcome, regardless of whether you think reputation points should be gained by answering questions or making edits.

Comment: You seem to have completely misread the reasons of the OP. The reputation is not the issue. The bumping of old questions (in bulk) is.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, no, I didn't. I just didn't read the comments. If the OP had put that in his question, I would've responded differently, so I don't see a reason for downvoting my answer. The questions should be self-sustained and not require reading of comments to address them. Also, if that was his major concern, why "confuse" us by putting the descriptor "low-rep" in the title if reputation is not an issue? Regardless, I stick to my point. If the edit is valid, let the post be bumped. So, seriously, I would like to know how my answer has not addressed the question and required a downvote.

Comment: The reason for putting "low-rep" there is that other users do not need to get their edits approved.

Comment: @Ryker: Meta and main have slightly different uses for the voting system. Downvotes on meta (almost always) mean that the downvoter does not agree with your stance, not that the quality of the answer is bad.

Comment: @EricStucky, I didn't know that, so thanks for letting me know. Still, for some unknown reason, I must have rustled a lot of feathers with my answer, and I can't really see what it was that did it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, OK, again, this was not evident to me from the post and I didn't know that was supposed to be the reasoning he put it there. In fact, reading the first few comments now, it seems as if reputation indeed was at least part of what caused his irritation (see discussion with robjohn). Also, I thought this site was aimed at addressing specific questions as they stand on their own rather than the paraphernalia that comes with it in the form of comments etc.